# Graphics performance of 945GME

Tags: 10.10, graphics, performance

Edit: Since setting Appearance -> Visual Effects up to a stunning "Normal", I now get ~35 FPS in `glxgears` right after login, with nothing else running :(

I'm getting terrible graphics performance in **NeverWinter Nights** (native with SoU+HotU+CEP2) on my Eee PC 1005HAB. Even with all graphics settings (including the "advanced" ones) at minimum I get about 2-10 FPS, depending on the scene. **Firefox** is really sluggish as well - Changing tabs often takes a second, scrolling is laggy, and typing this I notice the delay between pressing keys and seeing the text on screen. The rest of the OS is running OK, although general performance seems to be even *worse* than my old Eee PC 900.

`glxgears` gives about 60 FPS, which is apparently as it should be (synchronized with the monitor refresh rate).

Bugs like [Launchpad #252094](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/karmic/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/252094) and the instructions for [Reverting the Jaunty Xorg intel driver to 2.4](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReinhardTartler/X/RevertingIntelDriverTo2.4) are old enough that I'm afraid following the instructions would render the system unusable.

Are there any tips for improving graphics performance on this system that are still relevant for 10.10?

```
$ uname -a
Linux l0b0eee 2.6.35-28-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 1 14:40:58 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux

$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GME Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:27ae] (rev 03)

$ glxinfo 
name of display: :0.0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a speculative guess -

I'm sure that you probably have read the same reports as me - your particular graphics card has significant issues probably either or both with the default intel driver and/or the actual kernel.

Can i suggest you first backup you system using a good imaging tool such as Clonezilla.

Try adding the glasen ppa [here](https://launchpad.net/~glasen/+archive/intel-driver) to see if an updated intel driver makes any difference.

The latest backported maverick kernel is v2.6.37-rc2 which can be installed using the instructions from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds?action=show&redirect=KernelMainlineBuilds)

However - if you want to take this step - my recommendation would be first to load an image of Natty onto a USB stick and see if your graphics issues are resolved.  The reason for this recommendation is that Natty will have the latest stable graphics driver and most up-to-date stable kernel.

Other-stuff to check:
Note - GLXGears isnt a good measure of measuring performance - it doesnt give an accurate view on performance.

1. Login as Ubuntu Classic and check that no visual effects are enabled (right click the background and check that Visual Effects are set to None.   What is MineCraft FPS?  i.e. this check will ensure that Compiz is not your issue.
2. Double check that you dont have Metacity Compositing mistakenly enabled

   gconftool-2 -s '/apps/metacity/general/compositing_manager' --type bool false

Comment: After upgrading to 11.04 the performance seemed to be the same, although Firefox 4 is not quite as sluggish anymore. Installing the new Intel driver seemed to make a difference at first, but I'm not sure - Minecraft is almost playable at the lowest settings (2-10 FPS or so), but `glxgears` still reports 30-40 FPS.

Comment: l0b0 - I've updated my answer with a couple of other checks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get better performance after adding yourself to the video group?

```
adduser USERNAME video
```

Comment: Nope. What difference does that normally do?

Comment: If there was a bug preventing you from full acceleration because you aren't root, this could workaround it. Happened to me, which is why I mention it.